# JSON and regex_replace in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, replace

I'd like to replace the the key1 and key2 values with the text in the condition key.

My expected answer is just a text - `foo && bar` .

Can we do this replace without a for loop? If not, let me know with for loop.

```
with t as (
select
    '{
     "key1":"foo",
     "key2":"bar",
     "condition":"key1 && key2"
    }' :: json as j)
select
    f.key,
    f.value
from
    t,
    json_each_text(j) f
```

Comment: Are `key1` and `key2` constants (i.e. there are only those and never others)

Comment: I'm afraid not. they can change.. but definitely they are aligned with the value in `condition` key. @a_horse_with_no_name